# Apache .htaccess redirect to an anchor

Tags: .htaccess, anchor

I'm trying to do a one-off damage-limitation redirection to an anchor on a page on a website. A wrong URL got published in some publicity material, like this:

```
https://mydomain.org.uk/A/B
```

when what I really wanted to publish was

```
https://mydomain.org.uk/A#B
```

Having looked at some other answers it seems that any redirect with an anchor needs to be an absolute URL. So I put this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule A/B https://mydomain.org.uk/A.php#B [NE,L]
```

(note, the .php is correct, A.php is the page file). And it just simply doesn't work. The browser simply loads A.php and displays it from the top.

I know that the rule pattern is matching, because if I make the target be a completely nonexistent page I get a 404 as expected.

Unfortunately my web hosting service doesn't let me use the Apache log, so it's hard to trace what's going wrong. Can anyone guide me to how to do the rewrite properly so that I pass the #anchor all the way through to the user's browser?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I worked around this by not doing any redirection in .htaccess. Instead I moved A.php to A/index.php and then created A/B.php containing a redirection. This works just fine, and solves my immediate problem. Nevertheless I'd really appreciate any help with the .htaccess approach, as it is something I'd like to understand for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `RewriteRule` is processed by the server, it basically changes internally which resource to access, without the browser noticing.

The only way to change the URL in the browser is to use the redirect flag. This will make the webserver send a HTTP `302` response with a `Location` header, which then will result in the browser changing the URL and requesting the new page. This new URL can contain an anchor.

In your case the following rule should work:

```
RewriteRule A/B https://mydomain.org.uk/A.php#B [NE,R,L]
```

Please keep in mind that anchors are a browser feature so they are normally not sent to the server and therefore neither appear in access logs nor can be used in a `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, that worked. I was aware that I can't use anchors in a RewriteRule pattern. I'm cross with myself - I had tried adding R=301 to the flags, and that didn't work, but just plain R (or, presumably, R=302 ??) does work, exactly as you say.
Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. I just tried `R=301` which worked in my setup, but maybe for some other reason might not work in yours/others. According to the documentation, `R` is the same as `R=302`.

Comment: So here's the weirdest thing. When I marked this answer as correct, I had already moved A.php to A/index.php; I removed A/B.php, added the corrected rewrite rule, and got the desired result. Then I moved A/index.php back to its original place A.php (removing directory A, of course) and now I'm back to the original problem: the redirect, which is now
  RewriteRule A/B https://mydomain.org.uk/A.php#B [NE,R,L]
no longer works as required; it gives the behaviour I first described, simply displaying A.php without the anchor. Is there something special about the site top level directory?

Comment: This is weird, indeed. I've tested it at site top level directory too and there should not be any difference. However, sometimes the browser cache gets in the way and gives strange results. Also, with `R` in the rewrite it should always get exactly that in the browser's URL bar. Have you tried using a wrong URL again for target to exclude another problem?